# How to put figures inside text?

Tags: graphics, positioning

I want to put figures (controller button icons) beside text, for a game manual, like this image:

[image: screenshot]

source: http://www.zeldacapital.com/manual/ootmanual.pdf page 17

Comment: You can use tikz with the `baseline` option.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have the figure, you can use `\includegraphics[scale=0.1]{*filename*}` of `graphicx`package directly in the text (not in an environment like `center` or `figure`). You can use the `scale` factor to fit the figure in the text.

Comment: how to control vertical position?, image is putting itself like a exponential value (i dont know how to explain)

Comment: i solved it using trim: [scale=0.4, trim= 0 30 0 0]

Answer (score 9):

Using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

Press the \tikz[baseline=-1.3ex]\node[circle,fill=blue!80,inner sep=1pt] (O) {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\textcolor{white}{A}}; Button

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, pretty amazing!, but actually i want to use xbox controller buttons, this blue circled "A" buttons is just an example about i want to do

images i want to put are here:
https://github.com/sgraham/gamepad.js/tree/master/images/Xbox360

Answer (score 6):

Similar to @Gonazalo Medina:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand*\circled[1]{\tikz[baseline=(char.base)]{
  \node[shape=circle,fill=blue!80,inner sep=2pt,text=white] (char) {\bfseries\sffamily #1};}}
\begin{document}
text on the left \circled{A}  text on the right
\end{document}
```

This yields:

[image]